# unix command to copy multiple files from different directories to one new directory

Tags: unix

I am newbie to unix command usage.
I would like to ask if there is a way to copy multiple files from multiple directories into 1 new directory?
example:

```
in /tmp/dirA --> it contains file A.run.log and A.skip.log
in /tmp/dirB--> it contains file B.run.log and B.skip.log
in /tmp/dirC --> it contains file C.run.log and C.skip.log
```

and i would like to have all

```
A.run.log
A.skip.log
B.run.log
B.skip.log
C.run.log
C.skip.log
```

into a new folder called `/tmp/dirNew`

Is there a unix command that able to do it? Really appreciate it. Thank you.

JS

Comment: You may want to explore `cp`, `mv`, `find`.  Some knowledge of globbing might also help.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
cp /tmp/dir?/* /tmp/dirNew
```

Comment: you'll need to `mkdir /tmp/dirNew` before the `cp` cmd. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /tmp -path "/tmp/dirNew" -prune -o -name '*.run.log' -exec cp {} /tmp/dirNew/ \;
find /tmp -path "/tmp/dirNew" -prune -o -name '*.skip.log' -exec cp {} /tmp/dirNew/ \;
```

Comment: thanks for the sharing. if the source directory pattern differ, how the commands above can be changed to? for example: /tmp/dirA and /tmp/abc/dirB and /tmp/efg/xyz/dirC, the files to copy is still A.run.log, B.run.log, C.run.log, A.skip.log, B.skip.log, C.skip.log.

Comment: @user3531570, look into the find manpage and experiment the `path` option. If you define your requirements clearly, I can give you a more suitable command.

Comment: Thanks perreal, in a more detailed explanation, for example, if there  are 3 users in 3 different work area (they can create the directory their own), user A==> /commonarea/dirA/ownerA/A.run.skip.log, user B==> /commonarea/dirB/xtradirB/ownerB/B.run.skip.log, user C==> /commonarea/C_own_dir/C.run.skip.log; and if user D (I am the user D) want to copy those A.run.skip.log + B.run.skip.log + C.run.skip.log, how should the user D find those *run.skip.log file when user A, B, C have it in different directory (with only the 1st is common area directory)?